# How to filter Play Recap after run Playbook in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm new to Ansible and i'm using it for a project where i run my playbook in 1024 hosts.
I managed to get my playbook running well but right now i need a way to filter the Play Recap that's showed after running the playbook.

```
PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************

100.80.80.1                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=2
100.80.80.3                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=2
100.80.80.4                : ok=3    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
100.80.80.5                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=2
100.80.80.6                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=2
100.80.80.7                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=2
100.80.80.8                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=2
100.80.80.9                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=2
```

This is a example of what it shows in my Play Recap, in this example i have only 8 hosts so it's easy to see what host changed or failed, the problem it's when i run my real playbook over the 1024 hosts and my play recap goes to 1024 lines and it's almost impossible to go reading every line to see what changed or failed.

So my question is, how do i filter the Play Recap to only show changed and failed hosts? Hiding OK and Skipped

I tried to use "**display_skipped_hosts= False**" and "**display_ok_hosts= False**" in my ansible.cfg but nothing changes.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: You mean, Show only hosts which have changed or failed tasks, but not hosts which have one or more skipped tasks?

Comment: Yes, i want to see only hosts with status "changed" or "failed" tasks. The other status can be hidden.

Comment: What should happen in case of `one.example.com            : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1`?

Comment: Be displayed because it was changed by one task.

But i don't really think that one case like this can happen in my script because in my script there is 3 tasks only:

The first ping the host to see if he is up, if it's then it's changed, if it's not then it's ignored.

The second task group only the hosts that responded to the ping, so if it was ignored on the task 1 it will be ignored again, if it was changed on the task 1 it will be changed again.

Than the 3 task applies only to hosts grouped in task 2, so here or it goes changed or failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys!

I find a solution for what i need and here goes the instructions for anyone with the same need as i.

---

```
cd /etc/ansible/playbooks
ansible-playbook (playbook_name).yaml | tee /etc/ansible/log/$(date +'%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M').txt
```

I go to my playbooks directory and exec my playbook using "tee" to set a specific log file

---

```
cd /etc/ansible/log
sed -n '/PLAY RECAP/,/-0300/p' (log_name).txt | grep -v "ignored=2"
```

Then i go to directory of my file and using the command sed along with grep i filter only the lines with actual changes in hosts because it's what i needed, but you can tweak for your needs.

---

And that is it! You should see a output like that:

```
    PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
100.80.80.4                : ok=3    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 19 seconds
```

That way i solved two problems at once which was a way to filter changed hosts and a way to have one log per playbook run.

Comment: Why using `tee` if Ansible has the built-in functionality to write logs to files and the name could also be specified from the console?

Comment: I just used it because i had more familiarity with it, but i will test using the built-in functionality too!

Answer (score 0):

Play recap shows the distribution of task statuses per host, not statuses of hosts.

`display_skipped_hosts` and `display_ok_hosts` parameters control the logging of tasks and don't affect the recap.

What you can do, though, is to use the `json` [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_callback.html) and filter the `stats` object of its output according to your requirements.

Also, you can set your own custom stats using [`set_stats`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_stats_module.html) module, enable `show_custom_stats` parameter, and filter the log output based on that.

You may also try to play with [`meta`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html) module to conditionally end the play for some hosts based on the same reason why they were skipped, but I'm not sure about it.

Finally, you can experiment with custom callback plugins such as [ARA Records Ansible](https://ara.recordsansible.org/), or write your own one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. I will look at those suggestions!

Alson, i tried to filter that using the "cat log | grep changed=3" and it does work but my log it's storing data of everything in just one file so when i use cat i'm seeing logs from olders playbooks runs. Can i have log file per playbook run? if could do that it will be easy to filter the log using "cat"

Comment: You can set the log path via the `ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH` environment variable and customize the filename: `ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=$(date +"%F-%T").log ansible-playbook <your_playbook>.yml`.